# rails convert html to image

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, rmagick

I'm looking for a way to convert html tags to a image on the fly...

That means, that I want to be able to make a image_tag with a path to a method which returns the image created form html.

I was looking for a solution on that, but couldn't come up with a proper way to solve that...

Any Ideas?

Maechi

Comment: After reading this twice, I'm still confused what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please let everyone know:  1) Why and 2) what tag types are you talking about?

Comment: Is the image an image _of_ some html code showing a set of tags, an image of a page as it would render in a particular browser, or are you trying to take a particular part of the page, say a paragraph tag and turn that into an image that displays that paragraph as an image - a text to image generator effectively. Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: I'm interested in this too.  
I'd like to 
1) render a page in html
2) convert the page into a jpeg
3) return the jpeg from the service call
All in real time

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208403/rails-imgkit-issues-in-exporting-images-with-html-and-css

Answer (score 33):

IMGkit can do the job ([details on github](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit))

> Create JPGs using plain old HTML+CSS

```
kit = IMGKit.new('http://google.com')
kit.to_jpg
kit.to_jpeg 
kit.to_png
kit.to_tif
kit.to_tiff
```

or in your controller

```
@kit = IMGKit.new(render_as_string)

format.jpg do
  send_data(@kit.to_jpg, :type => "image/jpeg", :disposition => 'inline')
end
```

Comment: what render_as_string without any parameters? I dont get it..could anybody point me somewhere? And should be render_to_string? In any cases, what does it do?

Comment: Could you edit one of those 'kit' into a File in order to send it via FTP?

Comment: @JakubKuchar http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string The first arg can be a path to the view you want to render as string, for example 'orders/summary'. The docs say it best: _It is similar to render, except that it does not set the response_body and it should be guaranteed to always return a string_.

Comment: If you are looking to convert a HTML into a *tiff* file `IMGKit` won't be enough as *tiff* support has been removed from the underlying `wkhtmltoimage` application.

Relevant commit: https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit/commit/378a8ae11d94afd012b0fee7839da9910a19ffb2

Comment: it's `render_to_string` now (rails 7 at least)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess here and guess that you want to convert HTML to an image, so take a "snapshot" of a web page or something. I'm not sure exactly how to do this in one step, but one way to do it is to use [PDFKit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit) to convert to PDF and then use RMagick to convert to whatever image format you want.

Comment: The reason someone would want to do this is to convert complex HTML layouts in to email friendly layouts.

Answer (score 1):

IMGKIT reqiured css with absolute url for any background image or other assets.
So you can generate it dynamically following this link https://coderwall.com/p/exj0ig and some steps as

**A)** Put your all images in assets/images folder of rails app

**B)** Install gem 'sass-rails' if not install https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

**C)** create another css file name as css_file_name.css.sccs.erb

**D)** put your all other css file content in it.

**E)** In css file just put your image file name as below:
background-image: image-url('image.png');

**F)** Use assets pipline (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline)
Run below command as your app mode: 
(1) Development Mode: RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
(2) Production Mode: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

**G)** In your config/environments/

(1) In development.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "YOUR LOCAL HOST URL i.e YOUR_LOCALHOST_ADDRESS"

(2) In production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com" /*YOUR ADDRESS*/

**H)** And last relate your stylesheet with IMGKIT as below

```
html_content = "YOUR HTML CONTENT"
kit = IMGKit.new(html_content, height: 900, transparent:true, quality:10) /*YOUR SETTING*/
kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/public/assets/application.css"
file = kit.to_file(Rails.root + "public/pngs/" + "screenshot.png") /*YOUR IMAGE NAME*/
send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/pngs/screenshot.png", :filename => "screenshot.png", :type => "image/png",:disposition => 'attachment',:streaming=> 'true') /*YOUR ADDRESS WHERE U WANT TO STORE PNG FILE*/
```

**I)** Restart server and enjoy!!!!!

[**NOTE:** After every changes please run assets pipline command to get latest application.css which is made from .sccs.erb extension file.]

Answer (score 0):

1. write a regular action, such as `render_html_action` to render html page
2. write another action, such as `snapshot_action`, using [puppeteer-ruby](https://github.com/YusukeIwaki/puppeteer-ruby) to snapshot the `render_html_action` rendered html as jpg or pdf

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [Grover](https://github.com/Studiosity/grover#running-on-heroku) - Uses Puppeteer under the hood.

I would caution against using IMGKit given that wkhtmltoimage [is essentially depreciated](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/status.html). Wkhtmltopdf is based on QtWebkit which is long deprecated. We found numerous issues with wkhtmltoimage, as an example some modern CSS (like flexbox) is not supported.