# Rendering a Rails partial to an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, view, paperclip, partial

So, I have a problem and my initial question is: **Is this possible?**

I'm allowing people to customize the appearance of something using css, and then once they save it I want to turn it into thumbnails to use to display it in various other places (in other sizes maintaining that same aspect ratio).

So the question is, is it possible to do something where I render that partial, then it's saved to an image that I can upload to aws in various sizes etc. using paperclip? Once I get the image I can do the paperclip part, but it's getting that partial to render the html/css and save that to an image... Thoughts?

Just know, any help and/or thoughts at all would be great!

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: This might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563707/rails-convert-html-to-image

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! Ugh, I thought I tried googling everything... apparently far from it. If you could post that as the answer I'd mark it as right. Though, I'm not 100% sure what the proper stack overflow etiquette  is here... maybe I should just erase the question ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

> [rails convert html to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563707/rails-convert-html-to-image)